# How to dockerize Scala project that add external libraries using unmanagedBase?

Tags: docker, scala, opencv, sbt

I'm using **opencv_480** to find **Image blurriness** for that I have added **opencv-480.jar** as an external library in **build.sbt** using **unmanagedBase** , after adding jar file I'm able to import its libraries and used them successfully in my **sbt-shell**.

but now I want to dockerize my project, for that I created an Image of my scala project using **sbt-native-packager** and write a docker compose for it, when I do **docker-compose up** it through an error.

```
scala-service_1  | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java480 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
scala-service_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
scala-service_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
scala-service_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
scala-service_1  |  at blurriness.CheckBlurry$.isImageBlurry(CheckBlurry.scala:11)
```

here is my **build.sbt**

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "document-verification"
  )

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

Docker / packageName := "document-identification-test"

Docker / version := "0.0.1"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8085)

dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown
dockerAdditionalPermissions += (DockerChmodType.UserGroupPlusExecute, "/var/run/")

fork := true

    val openCVNativeLibPath = file("/opencv_lib/native_libs")
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "opencv_lib"

run / javaOptions += s"-Djava.library.path=${openCVNativeLibPath.getAbsolutePath}"

Docker / daemonUserUid := None
Docker / daemonUser := "root"

dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:11"
```

I have added my **native-libs** and **opencv-480.jar** in **opencv_lib** directory (opencv_lib created at root level).

here is my main class **CheckBlurry.scala**

```
import logfactory.LogFactory.logger
import org.opencv.core.{Core, CvType, Mat, MatOfDouble}
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc

object CheckBlurry extends App {
  def isImageBlurry(imagePath: String): Boolean = {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)
    val image = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath)
    val gray = new Mat()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    val laplacian = new Mat()
    Imgproc.Laplacian(gray, laplacian, CvType.CV_64F)
    val variance = new MatOfDouble()
    Core.meanStdDev(laplacian, new MatOfDouble(), variance)
    println("variance: {}", variance.get(0, 0)(0))
    val threshold = 35
    variance.get(0, 0)(0) < threshold
  }

  val isBlurry = isImageBlurry("src/main/resources/blurImage.png")
  
  if (isBlurry) {
    logger.info("Image is blurry")
  } else {
    logger.info("Image is not blurry")
  }
}
```

My project Image is (created using sbt-native-packager)

```
document-identification-test                   0.0.1           eb7f17b525d1   3 hours ago     736MB
```

my **docker-compose** is

```
version: '3'
services:
  scala-service:
    image: document-identification-test:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    volumes:
      - ./opencv_lib:/opencv_lib
```

am I dockerizing my project in a right why or doing some mistake?
why my project is running in sbt-shell but throwing error in docker container?

Comment: Did you check the generated Docker file? Does it include the extra lib? If exec-ing in the container, do you see the lib?

Comment: @GaëlJ yes I exec in container , the files are there.

Comment: I hadn't see your docker-compose file. I thought you would embed the extra lib in the image. You need to customize the java.library.path in the container then, as the error states it's not searching in /opencv_lib. Do the same as you did for the "run / javaOptions" but for the image/container.

Comment: @GaëlJ I have add "java.library.path" in docker by using "Docker / dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  Cmd("ENV", s"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$openCVNativeLibPath")
)"

but get another error which is 
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4af53ee291, pid=1, tid=48
ava VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.21.9.1 (11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use OpenCV in docker container - you have to install OpenCV in it first. And you can do this using commands in **build.sbt**.

Firstly make a directory in root **opencv4** and then paste two files in it **libopencv_java480.so** and **opencv-480.jar** (these files will be located at **/usr/local/share/java/opencv4**).

Here is the updated build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "document-verification"
  )

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

Docker / packageName := "document-identification-test"

Docker / version := "0.0.1"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8085)

dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown
dockerAdditionalPermissions += (DockerChmodType.UserGroupPlusExecute, "/var/run/")

fork := true

Universal / javaOptions += "-Djava.library.path=/opencv4"

Docker / daemonUserUid := None
Docker / daemonUser := "root"

dockerBaseImage := "amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.18-jdk"

dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  Cmd("RUN", "apk", "add", "--no-cache", "bash make cmake g++ wget unzip"),
  Cmd("RUN", "apk", "add", "--no-cache", "linux-headers"),
  Cmd("RUN", "wget", "-O", "opencv.zip", "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.8.0.zip"),
  Cmd("RUN", "unzip", "opencv.zip && rm opencv.zip"),
  Cmd("RUN", "mkdir", "-p", "build && cd build && cmake ../opencv-4.8.0 && make -j4 && make install")
)
```

Here is the docker compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  testservice:
    image: document-identification-test:0.0.1
    container_name: document-verification
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources:/src/main/resources
      - ./opencv4:/opencv4
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    networks:
      - verification-network

networks:
  verification-network:
    driver: bridge
```